# filtering a queryset based on the results of anoter one

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

So I have a model called post and one of its fields is a foreign key to user model, And i have another model called subscriptions which has 2 foreign keys one referring to the user and the other one referrs to another account and i want to filter the post queryset to only show posts from people where there is a subscription object where the user is subscribed to the creator of the post. My models look like this:

```
class post(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Account,blank=False,null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class subscriptions(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Account,blank=False,null=False,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='subscriber')
    subscribed_to = models.ForeignKey(Account,blank=False,null=False,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='subscribed_to')
```

i tried doing this in the views

```
posts = post.objects.filter(creator__in = request.user.subscribed_to)
```

but it return nothing

This is my account model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    addresse = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    party_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profil_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profil_pics/',blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(default=date.today())
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date_joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last_login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','first_name','last_name','addresse','birthday','city']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please provide the code of Account model?

Comment: @EliakinCosta Thank you , I edited it to include the account model

Comment: It relationship check seems to be more like this [ post.creator = subscriptions.subscribed_to AND subscriptions.subscriber = request.user ]. Sorry I'm not used to django implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it in one query.

```
Post.objects.filter(creator__subscribed_to__subscriber=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research i ended up finding some infos that lead to:

```
subs = subscriptions.objects.filter(subscriber=request.user).values_list('subscribed_to')
posts = post.objects.filter(creator__in = subs
```